# Overwrite existing AVAsset

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I can select images from camera roll and then i save that to custom album.
This increases count due to duplicate save

What should i do to remove asset or any other way ?

```
  __block  UIImage *imTransfer=nil;
            PHImageRequestOptions * imageRequestOp = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
            imageRequestOp.synchronous = YES;



            [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:photoAssety options:imageRequestOp resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info) {

                 imTransfer=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                   NSLog(@"info = %@", imTransfer);
            }];


            __block PHFetchResult *photosAsset;
            __block PHAssetCollection *collection;
            __block PHObjectPlaceholder *placeholder;

            // Find the album
            PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
            fetchOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title = %@", BottomAlbumName_string];
            collection = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum
                                                                  subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAny
                                                                  options:fetchOptions].firstObject;
            // Create the album
            if (!collection)
            {
                [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
                    PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *createAlbum = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetCollectionWithTitle:BottomAlbumName_string];
                    placeholder = [createAlbum placeholderForCreatedAssetCollection];
                } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                    if (success)
                    {
                        PHFetchResult *collectionFetchResult = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithLocalIdentifiers:@[placeholder.localIdentifier]
                                                                                                                    options:nil];
                        collection = collectionFetchResult.firstObject;
                    }
                }];
            }

            // Save to the album
            [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
                PHAssetChangeRequest *assetRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest changeRequestForAsset:photoAssety];
                placeholder = [assetRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset];
                photosAsset = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:collection options:nil];
                PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *albumChangeRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:collection
                                                                                                                              assets:photosAsset];

               // [albumChangeRequest removeAssets:@[placeholder].firstObject];
                [albumChangeRequest addAssets:@[placeholder]];

                  [self toggleFavoriteForAsset:photoAssety];





            } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                if (success)
                {


//                        NSString *UUID = [placeholder.localIdentifier substringToIndex:36];
//                        self.photo.assetURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=%@&ext=JPG", UUID];
//                        [self savePhoto];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NSLog(@"%@", error);
                    }
                }];
```

Comment: What is your code trying to achieve?   Generally you don't want to delete from the Camera Roll as users expect photos they've taken to continue to exist in the Camera Roll.  If you assign the photo to an album, the photo isn't duplicated.  What count are you talking about in "This increases count due to duplicate save" and why do you think it's a problem?

Comment: as we add the photos in new album from camera roll same as i want to do my app..